'useStateValue' is giving 'TypeError: undefined is not iterable'
I was creating an Amazone clone for my project. While creating the checkout page, I got an TypeError.It pops due the "useStateValve()", saying "undefined is not iterable".I'm using the useStateValve to pull my data in dispatching process but this error won't make it possible .I've tried everything and still unable to solve this issue.I'm making this project with reference of a youtube channel- clever programmer.Following is the code which creates the error, along with the code from where it is initiated.
import React from 'react';
import "./Product.css";
import { useState } from './StateProvider';


function Product({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
    const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    console.log("this is added to the basket");

    const addToBasket = () => {
       dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
        item: {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            image: image,
            price: price,
            rating: rating,
        },
       });
    };
    
  return (
    <div className='product'>
        <div className='product-info'>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p className='product-price'>
                <small>$</small>
                <strong>{price}</strong>
            </p>
            <div className='product-rating'>
                {Array(rating).fill().map((_, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>⭐</p>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src={image} alt=''/>
        <button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to Basket</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product

import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";

//Prepares the data layer
export const StateContext = createContext();

//Wrap our app and provide the data layer
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

//pull information from the data layer
export const useStateValue  = () => useContext(StateContext);

[image showing the error](https://i.sstatic.net/rBGxW.png)

I tried many ways but it isn't helping me.It works as, whenever we tap the add to the basket in amazon app while buying any product the details of the product should go to the chechout page,.ie. the shopping cart.
PLease help me through this issue

StateProvider.js doesn't export any useState variable. Where is StateProvider the provider component rendered? What are reducer and initialState that are passed as props? I suspect you are not passing a correct initial state value. Please [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.
